# SharePoint 2013 Continous crawl question

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search

I have read lots of articles and Blog about continuous crawl, and I need more details about the Continuous crawl interval settings. I am aware that the default is 15 min and min can be set to 1 min according to [MS article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219802%28v=office.15%29.aspx) Also, I am aware that more than more crawl can be run in parallel. Now, If I changed an item in SharePoint, does that mean it will start a new crawl? or is it based on the interval settings?

Here is an example. let us say I have a content source that takes 2 hours to crawl, and there is a current crawl still crawling the content. If I added/modified an item(s) would that start an new crawl or a new crawl will start based on the interval settings?

The reason I am asking this question is to be able to estimate how soon newly/modified items become available in search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuous Crawl run based on the time interval that is set. The good thing about this crawl is it can run parallel. That mean even if a Continuous Crawl is running once the interval it starts a new crawl and doesn't wait for the previous one to finish.

There is no monitoring for data changes, crawl will start based on schedule and pick up changes on the go.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying metadata will not trigger a crawl. The changes get logged to the change log and then next incremental or continuous crawl picks these up. It is very difficult to estimate when the changes will be picked up. Using a continuous crawl and basing it on that interval will be your best bet.